# Recover Lost Chrome Local Storage On Mac

Tags: google-chrome, mac, data-recovery, crash

This morning, when booting up my computer, I was alerted that a crash had occurred. When I opened Chrome, I realized that the local data was gone. Bookmarks were still there. However, important local data associated with my Chrome extensions were missing.

I was able to successfully look at the LevelDB files for my Chrome; however, I was unable to find anything. It is possible that the problem is that the folder where the local data was being saved changed, as it is now being saved in the Default folder, despite the fact that I am logged into an account in Chrome.

Additionally, checking my trash, I found a 'recovered files' folder. The folder takes up 69.2 GB of storage, and looks like this:

[image]

Additional:
Here is information on the crashes leading up to this:

[image]

These all happened while I was not using my computer.
Here is the information associated with a single crash:

[image]

The 'memory full' error is weird to me as I have 150 GB of free space on my machine.